# Can't compile using GCC on EC2

Tags: gcc, amazon-ec2

I am trying to compile a program using GCC on an AWS EC2 instance (c1.medium). The `cc1plus` processes are started correctly but after a while they stop using any CPU and the complete compilation process slows down and never finished.

In `top` I can see that the "`wa`" stat increases drastically at the same time as the compilation slows down.

Initially:

```
%Cpu(s): 88.1 us,  5.4 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.5 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  6.0 st
```

When the compilation processes slow down:

```
%Cpu(s):  0.2 us,  0.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 50.2 id, 49.3 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
```

I have tried a lot of different instance types, all with the same result.

As I understand it a high wa/iowait means a slow disk. I have therefore also tried to compile the application on different mounts in the ec2 instance, but this does not result in an improvement.

Does anyone have any experience in compiling c/c++ applications on EC2 and know how to solve this problem?

**UPDATE 2013-03-06 08:00**

As requested in the comments:

```
$ gcc --version 
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) 4.7.2
```

Comment: I guess you should specify the exact gcc version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to use a machine with more than 8 GB of RAM. Apparently GCC used a lot of RAM for compiling this specific program.

Answer (score 1):

Glad to see you found the solution yourself.

I've also noticed you can get this sort of hang-up behavior on a *micro* instance when doing processor heavy operations such as compiling code. Always do this kind of stuff on at least a small and then if necessary, convert back to a micro when you are done.